# How can I get the Views Per Hour stat for a YouTube video?

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-api

I checked the [Youtube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3) and it's mainly to do with adding functionalities related to the YouTube app rather than getting analytics data about videos.

There is a chrome extension called VidIQ that shows the views per hours of a particular video when going to the video's page on YouTube, so I tried reading the source code for it, but it is all compressed and I can't easily find what I'm looking for.

Could someone explain to me how VidIQ chrome extension is getting the views per hour stat for YouTube? Maybe it's not an official stat from Youtube but a rough estimate calculated by VidIQ. How do they get this information?

I tried debugging the VidIQ chrome extension to search through the source code but adding a simple html tag made the file corrupted and disabled the extension until I repaired it again. I'm having difficulties deciphering the source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of what VidIQ gets is from the [YouTube analytics api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics) and not directly from the YouTube data api although i would be they use some combination of both.

If you create a report that extracts views and run it every hour you should get the results you are looking for.

However i would be willing to be that they cache a lot of the data and do some internal analytics on it.  They would need to cache it as the YouTube analytics api only returns data for the last 90 days last i checked.

If your intent is to Reverse Engineer VidIQ you may need to accept that a lot of the data you are seeing is internally stored in their system and generated by them based upon the data that is avaliable in the YouTube Analytics API and the YouTube data apis.